# Can't pull image from gitlab private registry (openshift)

Tags: docker, gitlab, openshift

I tried to login with created user token (read_registry scope):

[image]

Also tried with project token. No success.
`Internal error occurred: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/groupname/projectname/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden`